# How do I add an interactive geographic map to my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, dictionary

I am creating a historical website and needs to create map of the world, and the places and countries are click able!
How can I create it?
what should I learn to know?
is there any tool to do it fast and nice?

Comment: Yes: an <img> with an image <map>

Comment: What you have tried so far???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the Google Maps API, or [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/) if you want to show your own map data.

If you haven't got your own map data yet you might find a tool like [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/) handy to help you build the map data.

If you don't want to start from scratch you might be able to adapt some of the free data here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GIS_data_sources

Comment: I want to creat my own map, I mean I want to create map of the world for about 1000 years ago! can I do it with google?

Comment: Probably not. Google allows you to add some of your own data, but if you want your own world sized map I recommend building it in QGIS

Comment: It will be a pretty big job BTW to create a world map with country data as it was 1000 years ago!

Comment: Something to get you started http://www.worldology.com/Europe/ancient_europe.htm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_geographic_information_system

Comment: Thanks for the time that you spend on my question. have a good life

Comment: @MatthewLock I think its should be a great job too.